# Get returnvalue in xmlcomment

Tags: c#, xml, stylecop

As a part of StyleCop, I am examining method-documentation. See the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// Copies the node.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileName">Name of the file.</param>
/// <param name="originalClassName">Name of the original class.</param>
/// <param name="newClassName">New name of the class.</param>
/// <param name="nodeName">Name of the node.</param>
/// <param name="ID">The identifier.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">doc</exception>
```

My goal is to get the returnvalue out of this block.

The text is given to me as an entire string. I tried parsing it into an XDocument to retrieve the return-element, but was not able to because of the lack of a root-element.

Is there any way for me to retrieve the return-value stored inside `<returns></returns>` tag? (Note that it is empty here by design, because that is actually what I want to discover; if it is empty.

Comment: Are you given the string with or without `///`? I'd just add a root node opener and closer, then parse it as XML, if you're given it without the `///`. Or can you post-process the XML file which is generated from this, instead?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am given the xml without `///`, yes. I can also retrieve the text as one entire string, but this includes linebrakes as shown in the xmlcomment itself. The object is either a XmlHeader (StyleCop-API) or string (with the linebrakes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this seems a bit dirty, but I'd do:

```
string xml = "<root>" + text + "</root>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement returns = doc.Root.Element("returns");
if (returns != null)
{
    string returnsDescription = returns.Value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are there no alternatives? Could I accomplish this with a regular expression perhaps?

Comment: @Matthijs: I would far rather use a bit of string concatenation followed by proper XML parsing than try to parse XML with a regular expression. It really should be valid XML, right? It's just missing a root...

Comment: it is valid xml, apart from having a root indeed. But it looks like a quick and dirty solution on one hand... Yet also not because of the excellent parsing afterwards. I'll go with it, thanks!